# Excel Userform stuck on .show

Tags: excel, vba

I have two user forms. The first is UI to allow different ways for data to be processed. The second is a progress bar. The first on works fine, but when the second one is called, it stalls on `.show`.

```
Sub ShowProgressBar()
  With ProgressBar
    Debug.Print "Progress Bar Called: " & Time
    .LabelProgress.Width = 0
    .Show
    Debug.Print "Progress Bar Shown: " & Time
  End With
End Sub
```

I've added `UserForm_Activate()` event to see if the form was looking for one and stalling there. It called it, but never moved off the `.show`. I've seen this by it not going to the second `debug.print` statement. I've used `ctrl+break` and the `.show` is always the line highlighted. I've tried hiding the first form to see if there was an issue there, but no luck.

Code Calling the userform:

```
Me.Hide
ProgressBar.ShowProgressBar
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to solve? I would like to keep this as a separate Userform so it can be used in other projects.

Comment: read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251540.aspx   it is modal by default:   When a UserForm is modal, the user must respond before using any other part of the application. No subsequent code is executed until the UserForm is hidden or unloaded.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.